# how to select CSVs into rows along with another column in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have something like the following data in a table:

```
id    str
--    --------------------
 1    123,456,234
 2    17,54,22
 3    4,7
 4    432
 5    1,82,2
```

I want a SELECT statement that will give me the id and the str value seperated.  For example I want the following output from the sample above:

```
id     str
--     ----------
 1     123
 1     456
 1     234
 2     17
 2     54

etc
```

How do I get this result in sqlserver 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Split` function. I'm using this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

Now you can use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT Id, Item As Str
FROM dbo.TableName
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(str, ',')
```

[INNER JOIN vs. CROSS APPLY](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/)

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57d9d/2) with your sample data.

```
ID  STR
1   123
1   456
1   234
2   17
2   54
2   22
3   4
3   7
4   432
5   1
5   82
5   2
```